# Combining a list of onset-offset tuples if the previous element's offset equals the next element's onset

Tags: python, numpy, sorting, list-comprehension

Is there any standard library Python or Numpy operation for doing the following:

```
my_array = [(1, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 7), (10, 12), (12, 17), (21, 24)]
new_array = magic_function(my_array)
print(new_array)
```

```
> [(1, 7), (10, 17), (21, 24)]
```

I feel like something in `itertools` should be able to do this, seems like something a lot of people would use. We can assume the list is sorted by onset times already. It wouldn't be hard to do that anyway, you'd just use the `sorted` function with a key on the first element.

Apologies if this question has already been asked, wasn't sure how to word this problem, but this could be seen as a list of onsets and offsets and I want to merge elements with adjacent/equivalent timing.

**EDIT**: Inspired by @[chris-charley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/35812/chris-charley)'s answer below, which relies on some third party module, I just wrote up a small function which does what I wanted.

```py
import re
def magic_function(mylist):
    # convert list to intspan
    intspan = ','.join([f'{int(a)}-{int(b)}' for (a,b) in mylist])
    # collapse adjacent ranges
    intspan = re.sub(r'\-(\d+)\,\1', '', intspan)
    # convert back to list
    return [tuple(map(int, _.split('-'))) for _ in intspan.split(',')]
```

Here is the same function generalized for floats also:

```py
import re
def magic_function(mylist):
    # convert list to floatspan
    floatspan = ','.join([f'{float(a)}-{float(b)}' for (a,b) in mylist])
    # collapse adjacent ranges
    floatspan = re.sub(r'\-(\d+\.?\d+?)+\,\1', '', floatspan)
    # convert back to list
    return [tuple(map(float, _.split('-'))) for _ in floatspan.split(',')]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[intspan](https://intspan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) has the methods `from_ranges()` and `ranges()` to produce the results you need.

```
>>> from intspan import intspan
>>> my_array = [(1, 3), (3, 4), (4, 5), (5, 7), (10, 12), (12, 17), (21, 24)]
>>> intspan.from_ranges(my_array).ranges()
[(1, 7), (10, 17), (21, 24)]
```

Comment: Thanks @chris-charley, I've edited the original post with a solution inspired by this intspan module you've linked.